# Datatype for column with letters (non-numbers) in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, database-schema

Which datatype is best for declaring a column in a table which can contain only letters and not numbers in postgresql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing is to create a domain on varchar with a check constraint.

```
create domain textonly text check (value not similar to '%[0-9]%');
```

Then you can use that as a data type that prevents digits.

```
pagetest=# create table dtest (test textonly);
CREATE TABLE
pagetest=# insert into dtest values ('abc');
INSERT 0 1
pagetest=# insert into dtest values ('ab2c');
ERROR:  value for domain textonly violates check constraint "textonly_check"
pagetest=#
```

Comment: Thanks :) A little modification in your answer did the trick.